# Replace each pixel in a numpy array with a formula

Tags: python, image, numpy, matrix

I have a numpy array, which represent image pixels,
shape of the array is `(500, 800, 3)`
I need to multiply each pixel with the formula:

```
pixel_color = r * 0.299 + g * 0.587 + b * 0.114
```

So, `[r, g, b]` -> `[pixel_color, pixel_color, pixel_color]`

How can I do this with numpy operations?

Comment: Does the last (inner) dimension contain the rgb values? And if so, do you want to end up with a two dimensional array?

Comment: @9769953 It's a grayscale shades of rgb

Comment: I think you're looking for[`vectorize`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html).

Comment: There are no grayscale shades of rgb; that doesn't mean anything. Do you mean the (relative) values of the three colours, or a three dimensional grayscale picture?

Comment: @9769953 Relative values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for the weighted average of pixels.

```
a = np.ones(shape=(500,800,3))
gray_image = np.average(a, axis=2, weights=[.299, .587, .114])
```

Then, to get back to the original shape, you can use np.repeat with a new axis.

```
np.repeat(gray_image[:,:,np.newaxis], repeats=3, axis=2)
```

Comment: Thanks for the `np.repeat` example, very relevant here!